# Android can not restore purchased in app purchase (v3) items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, restore

I successfully implemented in app purchase and worked well, but whenever I tried to restore any previously purchased item(s) the queryInventory() method always return an empty inventory. Any solutions?

How did I test:

1. I used a random Android device downloaded my App from play store, purchased an item, deleted the app, downloaded the app again, purchased the same item (with the same account), charged me again.
2. Connected to eclipse with test device and test account, purchased several items, then check adb logcat of queryInventory() returned inventory list size = 0, but the returned result is successful ("BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK (0)").

**Query inventory code:**

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    logDebug("mHelper setup failed.");
                    complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                logDebug("mHelper setup successful. Querying inventory....");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
```

**Receive query result code:**

```
     // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items we own
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                logDebug("Query inventory failed.");
                complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            logDebug("Query inventory was successful.");

            // Check for items delivery
            for( int i = 0; i < purchaseOptions; i++ ) {
                if (inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_ITEMS[i])) {
                    logDebug("We have " + SKU_ITEMS[i] + " restored.");
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ITEMS[i]), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Added a snippet of code, any help?